# Why non-space elements in string aren't changing to upperCase

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to write a function to change the characters in a string at even indices to uppercase. I don't want my program to count the spaces as an even index, even if it falls on an even index.

For example: 'This is a test' => 'ThIs Is A TeSt'

I originally had this solution, but I could not get it to work to ignore the space characters when counting the even indices.

```
function toWeirdCase(string) {

return string.split("").map((x,i) => i%2=== 0 && x!== " " ? x.toUpperCase() : x).join("")

}
```

This is my second attempt and I don't know why the string elements aren't actually changing to uppercase. Any help on this would be appreciated. It is just returning the original string.

```
function toWeirdCase(string) {
  let indexCount = 0;
  let isSpace = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === " ") {
      isSpace = true;
    }
    if (indexCount % 2 === 0 && !isSpace) {
      string[indexCount] = string[indexCount].toUpperCase();
    }
    indexCount++;
    isSpace = false;
  }

  return string;
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify a string primitive value.

Comment: Strings are immutable in JavaScript (same as a lot of languages, for that matter). Make sure to always work in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)!

Comment: Side note; your expected results would not happen with a simple %2 check.  The `I` would be lowercased as it is in position 5.

Comment: @Taplar a simple %2 would work with a custom counter, as opposed to the index.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewind the index counter for a single word.

```js
function toWeirdCase(string) {
    return Array
        .from(
            string,
            (i => x => (/[a-z]/i.test(x) ? i++ : (i = 0)) % 2 ? x : x.toUpperCase())
            (0)
        )
        .join('');
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('This is a test')); // 'ThIs Is A TeSt'
```

Comment: Hi Nina! I think you may have meant to use `index++` instead of `++index`?  Otherwise the initial lowercase character will be capped, or, if the first character of the string is lowercase, it'll reverse the capitalization :)

Comment: Also - funnily, I actually used the closure/reduce pattern I didn't initially understand in one of your previous answers, and used it in my answer to this question. so... thanks! haha.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer:

You can use a modified `reduce` function that utilizes a closure as a character counter. This has the benefit of completing the transformation in one pass:

```
["", ...str].reduce((n => 
     (r, c) => r += /\s/.test(c) ? c : c[`to${n++ & 1 ? "Lower" : "Upper"}Case`]())(0)
);
```

---

### Example:

```js
const biUpperCase = str => ["", ...str].reduce((n => 
     (r, c) =>r += /\s/.test(c) ? c : c[`to${n++ & 1 ? "Lower" : "Upper"}Case`]())(0)
);

let test = biUpperCase("This is a Test");

console.log(test);
```

---

### Explanation:

- **n** is a **character counter** that keeps track of all non-space characters. You can think of this as an additional index that only worries about non-space characters.

  - We use this to determine whether or not a character is an *even* or *odd* non-space character by performing bitwise AND ( `n & 1` ) or, alternatively, by performing a modulus operation ( `n % 2` )
- **r** is the **accumulator** in the `Array.prototype.reduce` method. This is what is returned by our `reduce` method.

  - Since there was no secondary parameter to `Array.prototype.reduce`, the first index of the Array is used as the accumulator.

    - This is why we perform `["", ...str]` instead of simply `[...str]`.
    - Syntactically we could also have written `[...str].reduce( fn , "" )` instead of `["", ...str].reduce( fn )`, but this would alter our succinct code.
- **c** is the **current character** that we are looking at within the string array. We use `RegExp.prototype.match` to determine if it's a space character.

  - if it **is** we simply add the space to **r** ( our **accumulated** string )
  - if it **is not** we add a transformed character to **r** ( our **accumulated** string )

    - To determine which case transformation( **upper** or **lower** ) should be applied we check if **n** ( our **character counter** ) is *even* or *odd*.

      - if `n++ & 1` is **truthy** the case is **lower**
      - if `n++ & 1` is **falsy** the case is **upper**

---

### Aside:

You'll notice in the snippet and code I provided that I changed your parameter name **string** to **str**. The reason for this is because **String** is a built-in Constructor in JavaScript and it's best to never purposefully "cross the streams" when naming variables.

In the current way that you're attempting to use this variable it makes no difference since it's properly scoped, and truthfully it is up to you if you want to take my advice. Just be aware that it could lead to an annoying, *invisible* problem.

---

**Hope this Helps! Happy Coding!**

Answer (score 0):

A string in javascript is immutable so you will need  to do something like :

```js
let test = 'This is a test';
test = toWeirdCase(test); //Here you assign the result
```

And here is an example solution which ignores spaces in the count

```js
function toWeirdCase(string) {
  let count = 0;
  return string.split("").map((x) => {
   if(x !== " ")
 count++;
   if(count%2 === 0) return x.toUpperCase(); 
   else return x;
  }).join("")
}

let test = 'This is a test';
test = toWeirdCase(test);
console.log(test); //THiS iS a TeSt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like so:

```js
const str = "this is a test";

function toWeirdCase(str) {
  return str.split(" ").map(word => (
    [...word].map((c, i) => i % 2 ?
      c.toLowerCase() :
      c.toUpperCase())).join("")).join(" ");
}

console.log(toWeirdCase(str));
```

*Updated:* to set odd indexes `toLowerCase()` to handle edge cases like acronyms (ie: currency acronyms; `"CA"`, `"USD"`)
Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments mention, strings in Javascript are immutable. That being said, you can break down the input string on whitespace, do the transformations, and join back into a string, something like this -

```js
function toWeirdCase(sentence) {
  return sentence
    .split(' ')
    .map(word => word
      .split('')
      .map((c, i) => i % 2 ? c : c.toUpperCase())
      .join('')).join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the number of spaces in a variable in the functions scope.

```js
function toWeirdCase(string) {
    let spaceCount = 0;

    // Personal preference: I like the reduce fn for this, but a similar thing could be achieved with map
    return string.split('').reduce((value, letter, index) => {
        if (letter === ' ') spaceCount++;
        return value += ((index - spaceCount) % 2)
            ? letter
            : letter.toUpperCase();
    },'')
}
```

This returns the leter if the index ingoring the space count has a remainder when divided by 2.